# text recognition library, code for Android, Java?

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing

Can some one suggest a text recognition library or code for Android, Java? I need to do some text recognition from an image.
I have been able to find only Java code that is not fully compatible with the android image classes.

Answer (score 3):

I have done this task in `Blackberry` by using third party application of OCR on PHP server.

During my long R & D I have also worked on the below link of [github](https://github.com/abbyysdk/ocrsdk.com)

Comment: so the image is sent to a php server and the server returns the text?

Comment: ABBYY Cloud OCR SDK, from where you can use the code of PHP, java or Android too.

Comment: Sounds great I'll try using the php code, But if you find a java lib that those this please inform me. send the php please!!! :)